# Semantic-ui multiple How about customizing the display?

Tags: django, codeigniter, semantic-ui

I have created a multi-selection dropdown box, but I don't want it to increase by one every time I click on it. I envisioned that it would display no more than three values, and if it did, it would display "4 for 10 selection", is there anything I can do to make this happen? I have tried this method but it gives me an error.

```
//Customize the text that is displayed after multiple selections
        onLabelCreate: function(value, text) {
          if ($('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('get value').length > 3) {
            return '4 of 6 selected';
          }
        }
```

Comment: This looks like a JavaScript question. Can you remove the django and codeigniter tags please?